# Retrieve first key-value pair from a dictionary in Python without using list, iter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In case I have a huge dictionary `my_dict` with a complex structure.

```
my_dict = {'complex_key': ('complex', 'values')}
```

If I want to see its first key-value pair (to understand whats inside), currently I use:

```
list(my_dict.items())[0]
```

However, this dublicates all the keys in the memory. It is also inconvienient, because `pdb.set_trace()` does not execute expressions starting with `list`. It is possible to use iterator:

```
next(iter(my_dict.items()))
```

However, its inconvenient, because I cannot access n'th element easily.

Is there any other easy way to access key-value pairs of `dict_items()`?

In Python 2.7 this expression used to work:

```
my_dict.items()[0]
```

**Update** Ended up using:

```
tuple(my_dict.items())[0]
```

This approach at least overcomes the `pdb.set_trace()` limitation. It also allows to easily access n'th element and does not require any imports like `from itertools import islice`.

Comment: You can use `islice` to get the nth element, though. That expression in Python 2 is equivalent to `list(my_dict.items())[0]`

Comment: You would save a lot of memory and time using `itertools.islice()` as @juanpa.arrivillaga says, there is nothing wrong with importing from the standard library

Comment: How on Earth is `tuple(my_dict.items())[0` acceptable but `list(my_dict.items())[0]` isn't?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `pdb` - Python debugger has a command `list`, which overrides all code lines starting with `list`. If you want to execute a line starting with `list` in `pdb` you have to write something like `pass; list(..`. Using `tuple` allows not to think that I am in Python debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `my_dict.items()[0]` worked in Python 2.7 and not in Python 3 is because in Python 2 it returned a list and in Python 3 it returns a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

To get the same behavior, you have to wrap it in `list()` or `tuple()`.

The most memory efficient way would be to create a tuple of the keys.

```
keys = tuple(my_dict.keys())
my_dict[keys[0]]
```

However, whenever you change the dictionary, you'd have to update/recreate `keys`.

Another thing to note is order is not guaranteed before Python 3.7, though once `keys` is created, it's order is.

Comment: Using `tuple()` isn't memory efficient at all, it dumps all the keys into memory

Comment: A tuple of keys is more efficient than a list of items.

Comment: a tuple may use slightly less memory than a list to store the same items, but there is no need to store them at all here to access the first item

Comment: I agree, which is technically the question asked, but within the question, he said ``iter()`` was inconvenient because he "cannot access n'th element easily" I took that to mean he will be accessing other elements and ``iter()`` or ``islice()`` would be inefficient for a large dictionary.